# Cannot detect Media Key within an audio element

Tags: javascript, html, audio, media

I can't seem to use my keyboard's Media Play/Pause button in any program I try to use it in. I even tried to make a copy of the example used in [What PWA Can Do](https://whatpwacando.today/audio). Here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>

  </head>
  <body>
  <audio controls src="acknowledged.wav"></audio>

    <script>
        if('mediaSession' in navigator) {
            let player = document.querySelector('audio');
            console.log(player);
            console.log(navigator.mediaSession);
            navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
                title: 'Shadows of Ourselves',
                artist: 'Thievery Corporation',
                album: 'The Mirror Conspiracy',
                artwork: [
                    {
                        src: 'https://whatpwacando.today/src/img/media/mirror-conspiracy256x256.jpeg',
                        sizes: '256x256',
                        type: 'image/jpeg'
                    },
                    {
                        src: 'https://whatpwacando.today/src/img/media/mirror-conspiracy512x512.jpeg',
                        sizes: '512x512',
                        type: 'image/jpeg'
                    }
                    ]
            });
            
            navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', () => player.play());
            navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', () => player.pause());
            navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', (details) => {
                const skipTime = details.seekOffset || 1;
                player.currentTime = Math.max(player.currentTime - skipTime, 0);
            });

            navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', (details) => {
                const skipTime = details.seekOffset || 1;
                player.currentTime = Math.min(player.currentTime + skipTime, player.duration);
            });

            navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekto', (details) => {
                if (details.fastSeek && 'fastSeek' in player) {
                player.fastSeek(details.seekTime);
                return;
                }
                player.currentTime = details.seekTime;
            });

            navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', () => {
                player.currentTime = 0;
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried placing the logic inside a setTimeout. I have interacted with the page before trying to use the Media Key, even pressing Play/Pause on the element with my mouse. Whenever I do press a Media Key, the media of another tab is played/paused instead. If no other media on my computer is active, nothing happens.

I've tried this through both opening the index.html file within a browser, as well as the Visual Studio Live Server. This happens on Chrome 110. I also tried the file-opening option within Firefox 91.7.0esr. Both of these were on Debian 10. Then, I transferred the files over to a Windows 10 computer, and tried opening the file using Chrome 114, same results.

Thank you for your time!